Deciphering a courthouse note from 1612
In a courthouse book from 1612 I've found an entry related to my home village - it seems that the owner of that village ordered her servants to beat the local parish priest (so far I have no idea – why). Since it is written in Latin, with lots of abbreviations and legal terms, I have troubles translating it...
Could someone help me in deciphering this text into full Latin words/sentences, so that it will be possible for me to translate it?
Here are the scans of that book (I also attach images at the end of this post):

p. 102–103
p. 104–105

Here is a short dictionary:

cast. (castrum) - a gord (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gord_(archaeology))

capit. (capitaneus) - starosta (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starosta)

feria quinta in vigilia festi Sanctorum Trium - 5th day [of the week], in the eve of Holy Trinity

floren - florin (a gold coin)

palatinus - voivode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voivode); Mikołaj Zebrzydowski, mentioned in the text, was a voivode

Jan Frąckowicz - parish priest in Mszana (village)

Jan Goczałek z Kasinki - Kasinka is a village next to Mszana

Anna Belinowa - the owner of Mszana village

Mikołaj Zebrzydowski - Krakow's voivode since 1601


And here are the results I've got so far (probably – with some errors):
p. 102
Rela(tio)o pro parte Ioan(nnis) Franckowic P(aro)chi(alis) Mszanen(sis)

Minlis [Maiestatis?] G(ene)ralis Regni Pronidus Joannes Goczalek
de Kasinka, ad offici(um) et acta pr(aese)ntia Cast(rum) Capit(anensum)
O?? pvi veniens pubci ?it, quia feria quinta
in vigilia festi Sanctorum Trium Regnno pro???
pr??? has vadij Regalis Decimo Milli?? flore-
norum p??? Palo?? niter venerabilem Joanni
Frąckovici Paroch(ialis) Mszanen. et G??? Anna
Belinowa subiapifiram Crac. in ??? ??? ?? ac-
ta pr??? Cast?? Capit. Crac. oblatt subti-
tulo et sigillo Juris et M??? Nicolai Zebrzidov-
ski a Zebrzudovici Pal(atinat)i et G(ene)rali Crac(oviensi). Sniactino-
sig ze Cap??? c???, nomini et ex parte
suprabeni Joannis Frąckowic Plebani Msza-
nensis in cuiam villa Mszana Tenuta pra-
fata Anna Belinowa importanit et prafa-
ta Anna Belinowa pi???ter ibidemo
pr??? publicanit et notificanit de
iuris forma.

p. 103
Protestatio vulner(ablis) v(enera)b(i)lis Ioan Frąckovic con(tra?) Annam Belinoua

Ad office(um) et acta pr(aese)ntia Castrei Capitt. Crac. perf??
veniens v(enera)blis Joannes Frąckowic plebans Mszanen(sis).
solenni offici p(ub)lici? con grosam Anna Belinowa
Tenut?ie bonor Mszana questub et prottus estidem
quia ipsa no attentis ??? vadij Sac(ra). Regia M(aies)t(a)tis
nit cunt/eum protestan(tis?) et p(rae)dict Anna Belinowa
nit poss?? et ad act p?? paroch(ialis) et in ?esti qui??-
mo in contempt earum harum Sac(ra). Regia M(aies)t(a)tis
tepe no ila pridem ptto vest feria quarta post
Festu(m) Sanctor Trium Regn(i) proxi(mo) ptta prox(im)a
immisit vi et violent famules ??? fabi de no(m)e et
cogno(m)e melius notis in domus plebanat in villa
??? Mszana ??? poponis et manssimo ips(e?) prote-
stan, qui imncipi mandato et inp? p(rae)fata Belinowa
ibict eunt protestan vulneribus et verberib? mul-
tis ???pis limidi quia iam disparut afficimut
crines capelis eu???, fores domus eiunt et mensas
tuno et pa?iet conjecurt aliasg multas violentias
tempore et loca suis specificam et iure vindican eit
protestan mitulert, offici ??se prami??? ???

p. 104
cum eadeno Anna Belinowa iure pront competient
Actur, et in verific(aci)onem pramistor idem prattans
statut ar. offi(ci) prti Minlem G(e)n(er)alem Regni Pro-
vidum Joanneni Goczalek de Kasinka qui ???
idem pli stant pub??? recosit, qua sibi feria
quarta post festum Sanctor Trium Regn? Proxi(mo?)
p?? prox(ima?)a no(ct?)e et ex p(ar)te suprasen Joannus
Frąckowic Plebani Mszanen(sis). p??pa omiet con eant
Annam Belinowa obduct et protestat sunt, Atc?
in corpore eiunt p(ro)testan(…) Plebani ??? in manu
dentra vulnera duo concussa limida Item caput
concusum et decapilatu, nec no(men?) in domo ipsi ple-
baniali fores, parietes, mensas, consecat se viclisse
et debire unspexipe supserus Minlis offici p???
itirum atq(ue) iteram retu??, Insup ict prestans sla-
?? cor offi(ci) p(ublici?) Honestuno Melchiorem Frąc-
kovici f(ratr)em suum qui sic ict cor offi(ci) et actis
praesen p?? ??? vulnus sectum ornentum par-
num nondum exacte sanatt in dorso tum tempor
in domo Plebanali ips protestan per famules prae-
dicta Anna Belinowa ipsi illat, quod q(ui)dem vul(nerabil)-
us nondum exacte fanatt in corpore praedicti Melchior
/Melchioris Frąckovicz offici(…) pr(aesen)s vidit et debite
conspect in saipsit.




feria quinta in vigilia festi Sanctorum Trium "Thursday on the vigil of the Three Saints". I doubt that it is Trinity Sunday (whose vigil is always Saturday) which is referenced here. That said, I don't know which three saints are meant.

Could festum Sanctor Trium Regn? be festum sanctorum trium regum, feast of the three holy kings, i.e., Epiphany?

@Ilya, thank you very much for you in-depth analysis of that texts!
Also, that Dictionary you've mentioned will be very useful for me:)
Regarding your remarks to texts:
Ad. 1) Cracoviensis makes sense, as Mszana was part of Krakow (Cracovia) Voivodship.
Ad. 2) Now I see that Epiphany also makes sense, as those two notes (scans #56 and #57 in Acta  Castr. Crac. 38) were written down under the date 1612-01-20.
I've found the explanation of "vadium" in an article
"Latin and Polish vocabulaty in land laws till the end of 15th ct. – Terminology of real estate pledge" and it seems that "pledge" is the correct English translation here.
From what you've written it seems to me that some legal proceedings were already taking place before the beating, so I'll try to find some more notes before 1612-01-20.
Interestingly, there are further notes related to this case written down under 1612-01-25 (scans #71 and #72 in Acta  Castr. Crac. 38) – and it seems that this time Albertus Frąckowicz (probably Iohannis's son) was beaten by Anna Belinowa's servants (probably the same ones as before).

Thanks again! Regarding "Mszana" in vol. 33, I doubt it is about the village I live in, as there was not a single Orthodox/Greek catholic person here. However, "Mszana" was once quite a popular name (meaning typically a mossy place near a river) – e.g., one other Mszana (where Lemkos lived, who were orthodox/Greek catholic) is in nowadays southern Poland and two other Mszanas are in Lviv and Ternopil oblast, nowadays Ukraine, respectively.
